# How to move Jsplumb sources with its targets

Tags: jsplumb

![I want to move my **jsplumb** sources with its targets because i *draw these jsplumbs dynamically i want when i move each sources* its targets should also move with it?.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCmye.png)

Please help me download the image and help if there is a way to move My each sources of **Jsplumb** with it's **targets**
**when i drag any of the Jsplumb source it should move with it's targets?**

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you already have code to move source.

So following could help may be :-)

`var sourcecon = jsPlumb.getConnections({source: e}) ;
        for(i=0; i<sourcecon.length; i++) 
        {
            moveTarget(sourcecon[i].targetId) ;
        }`

moveTarget will be a function having code to move target.